# How to display mulitple records in a single row as comma separated

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2010, ms-access-2007, ms-access-2013

I'm newbie to MS Access.

How to display multiple records in a single row as comma separated in MS Access?

For example I have a table

```
state
AL
AK
MA
HI
TX
VI
GU
```

I want to retrive data as like below

```
State
AL, AK, MA, HI, TX, VI, GU
```

Can anyone help me with a query to do this?

Answer (score 0):

You can write the following "Crosstab" query so the will become fields:

```
TRANSFORM First(table1.state) AS FirstOfstate
SELECT "State" AS Expr1
FROM table1
GROUP BY "State"
PIVOT table1.state;
```

or in GUI:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

One option is to create a function that will return the concatenated list of values:

```
Public Function ConcatenateField( _
    ByVal Source As String, _
    ByVal Field As String, _
    Optional ByVal Separator As String = ";") _
    As String

    ' 2011-04-17. Gustav Brock, Cactus Data ApS, CPH.

    Dim rs          As DAO.Recordset

    Dim Rows        As Variant
    Dim Fields()    As Variant
    Dim Sql         As String
    Dim Item        As Integer
    Dim ItemList    As String

    ' Retrieve one field from table or query.
    Sql = "Select [" & Field & "] From [" & Source & "] Order By 1 Asc"
    Set rs = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset(Sql, dbOpenSnapshot)
    If rs.RecordCount > 0 Then
        ' Fill array.
        Rows = rs.GetRows(rs.RecordCount)
        ' Convert array to one dimension.
        ReDim Fields(UBound(Rows, 2))
        For Item = LBound(Rows, 2) To UBound(Rows, 2)
            Fields(Item) = Rows(0, Item)
        Next
        ' Create concatenated value list.
        ItemList = Join(Fields(), Separator)
    End If
    rs.Close

    Set rs = Nothing

    ConcatenateField = ItemList

End Function
```

Then use this expression:

```
=ConcatenateField("YourTableName", "State", ", ")
```

Or in a query:

```
Select Top 1 
    ConcatenateField("YourTableName", "State", ", ") As States 
From 
    YourTableName
```